# Is this step function expressed as a power series wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Here I have a step function expressed in the answer as a power series.

Please start at **Note that we can write...**

I think the power series is wrong as , at  any x, the value is infinite. However it is supposed to be the largest integer value as in the question. If someone could expand that power series and show me what is going as I am really confused then that would be really helpful! thank the heavens for your help. I am not sure how to write in Latex so heres a screenshot of the step function expressed as a power series.

[image: power series expression is in the middle of the page]

Comment: There are no power series here. A power series is  series of the form $\sum a_nx^{n}$.

Comment: the summation of the nX(x) terms, is that infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 and 0 should be reversed in the definition of $\chi_E$.

Comment: thanks for your answer ted..  but say I plug a x=5.5 into the power series expression, but i would end up getting infinity as the n goes from zero to infinity right?

Comment: No. If you reverse the 0 and 1, then for x=5.5, the term for n=5 is 5, while all the other terms are 0, so the total is 5.